# positon divs above area shape top and left position with jquery

Tags: jquery, position, imagemap

I feel I am so close to figuring this out but missing something...I am trying to position multiple divs above the top and left positions of multiple rect area shapes on my image map. Everything traces out fine to my console, but its not setting the top and left position to the divs

Below is what I have so far but feel I'm missing something..Any would be a life saver!!

Image Map:

```
  <img id="map" src="assets/img/header_bg2.png" width="1345" height="534"  border="0" usemap="#neighbormap" />
  <map name="neighbormap" id="neighbormap">
   <areaclass="button" data-target="one" shape="rect" coords="335,239,376,282" href="#" />
   <area class="button" data-target="two" shape="rect" coords="401,116,438,155" href="#" />
   <area class="button" data-target="three" shape="rect" coords="493,7,536,42" href="#" />
 </map>
```

Divs that need to be placed above top and left positions of area shapes:

```
 <div class="container">
   <div class="one">one</div>
   <div class="two">two</div>
   <div class="three">three</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
  $('#neighbormap').find('.button').each(function(index, element){
    var i, x = [], y = [];
    var c = $(this).attr('coords').split(',');
    var id = $(this).data('target')
    for (i=0; i < c.length; i++){
     x.push( c[i++] );
     y.push( c[i] );
    }
    var t = y.sort(num)[0];
    var l = x.sort(num)[0];

    $('.' + id).css({top: t, left: l, position:'absolute'});

    //console.log(t + ',' + l );

    function num(a, b){ return (a-b);
     }
})
```

UPDATE:

I was missing "px" It should be this:

```
  $('.' + id).css({top : t +'px',left : l +'px'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing "px" It should be: $('.' + id).css({top : t +'px',left : l +'px'});